# Windows 10 - Built-in Keyboard Not Working After Sleep

Tags: windows-7, laptop, keyboard, lenovo-laptop

A Lenovo IdeaPad's keyboard [laptop] has stopped working after sleep. I tried the following troubleshooting, but with no luck:

1. Update/ Uninstall/ Install Keyboard Driver from Lenovo Website
2. Turn Off Filter Keys
3. No Synaptics Drivers are installed.
4. End Cortana Process
5. Troubleshoot Keyboard
6. Windows Update
7. System Reset

The power button, which is part of the keyboard, is functioning, as I used it for turning on the laptop, and the power button light is on. The keyboard also functions when I enter the BIOS settings.

I formatted the laptop, but the keyboard is still not working; I also managed to get into the BIOS settings to change the boot sequence.  I'm able to press <kbd>F4</kbd> to boot to Safe Mode, but the keyboard in Safe Mode still doesn't work, nor does it work on the login screen or after logging in.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this issue?  Could it be a BIOS setting or a faulty driver?

Comment: Please run hardware diagnostics _(accessible either from the BIOS boot options or from within the BIOS)_.  Does the `F4` key work when booted to Windows?  Does the keyboard work when booted to a Linux LiveUSB (such as an Ubuntu install USB > choose Try Ubuntu when booted to it)?  If the keyboard works in the latter, the issue is some kind of corruption of the Windows OS system files, but if not, it's likely a hardware issue either with the laptop's keyboard, the ribbon cable that connects it to the motherboard, the ribbon cable header on the motherboard, or the motherboard itself.